# Error : CANNOT PUT /contacts/YYYY

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
  var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
//const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@sos-nwznc.mongodb.net/sos?retryWrites=true";
const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@sos-lriv2.mongodb.net/sos?retryWrites=true";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

var contacts;

client.connect(err => {
    contacts = client.db("sos1819").collection("contacts");
    console.log("Connected!");
});

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/",express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;  

app.put("contacts/:name",(req,res) =>{
       var updatedContact = req.body;
       var name = req.params.name;
       var ok=false;
        contacts.find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } }).toArray((err, contactsArray) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<contactsArray.length;i++){
                    if(contactsArray[i].name==name){
                         ok=true;
                        return updatedContact;
                    }else{
                         ok=false;
                        return contactsArray[i];
                    }
                }
                if(ok==true){
                    contactsArray = updatedContact;
                    res.sendStatus(200);
                }else{
                    res.sendStatus(400);
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Tengo este código en el que estoy intentando editar un contacto en concreto pero me sale el error de CANNOT PUT /contacts/nombre , no sé a que se debe, y pensaba que el código está bien

Comment: El código que muestras es el del servidor, sin embargo entiendo que la problemática que tienes se presenta es a nivel de la petición del cliente, o dentro de este mismo código?

Comment: Exacto , cuando el cliente hace la petición la salta el error

Comment: Suponiendo que el código está bien , porque lo mismo hay algún fallo

Comment: Si lo haces desde un cliente web es necesario tener en cuenta que la navegadores no pueden realizar peticiones POST ciertamente, lo que hacen es una petición PUT y envían un parámetro indicando que imitará a una petición POST, no sé si este sea el caso, has tenido ese manejo? Digamos si haces la petición desde Postman te funciona? Allí si podrás usar el POST naturalmente

Comment: Utilizo Postman , y al realizar el PUT en el body me salta lo que te he comentado

Comment: Estás usando express de lado del servidor?

Comment: Sí lo estoy utilizando para el lado del servidor

Comment: En la declaración del método de ruteo que tienes podrías agregar la barra de raíz antes del contacts y verificar de forma que quede /contacts/:name

Comment: Sigue generando el mismo error

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta con una proporción mayor de código por favor, que incluya la declaración de tú aplicación, la configuración y la escucha por el puerto seleccionado

Comment: Ya lo he editado

Comment: Ese no es el problema

Comment: En la parte inferior después del código que indicaste existe un listener?

Comment: si un app.listen al port y demás

Comment: El problema está en que te falta la barra inicial `/` en tu ruta en donde usas el *middleware*. Debería ser: `app.put("/contacts/:name",(req,res) =>{ ... });` Realiza esa modificación y comentas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Después de la declaración de tu variable app debes configurar el uso de parámetros codificados en la url por medio del siguiente código:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}));
```

Comment: Hola, creo que esto no soluciona el problema. `body-parser` es un middleware para *parsear* el `body` de un `request`. El problema que plantea el OP es diferente. El `path` al que está tratando de acceder no puede ser manejado por su aplicación.

Comment: Hola, lo replique en mi máquina agregando lo que indique y lo solucionó, validando previamente que al no tenerlo sucediera el error que se describe, entiendo bien lo que dices, sin embargo esa fue la razón por la cual lo compartí

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un fiddle y compartirlo para verlo? Disculpa por pedírtelo, lo que sucede es que tengo ya bastante tiempo usando Node y Express  y la verdad es que lo que planteas no me convence. Igual al momento de tener yo un fiddle para demostrarlo lo subiré. Saludos

Comment: El problema era la falta de una barra al inicio de la ruta. Como te dije, `body-parser` no tiene nada que ver en esto. Yo en principio pensé que el problema era el orden de los *middleware*, pero realmente el problema era de tipeo. Saludos

Comment: Lo que indicas se lo dije también a RoyalUp, sin embargo no funciono